# Program builds sucessfully but netbeans shows errors in the includes

Tags: c, netbeans

I have this program it builds but shows some errors in the includes

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
/** These two files are necessary for calling CTOS API **/
#include <ctosapi.h>


/** 
** The main entry of the terminal application 
**/
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    BYTE key;
        
    // TODO: Add your program here //
    CTOS_LCDTClearDisplay();
            
        CTOS_LCDTPrintXY(1, 1, "Hello");
            
        CTOS_KBDGet(&key);
    
    exit(0);
    }
```

here's the print of it:
[print of netbeans window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umKfg.png)

Edited:

here's the error:
Cannot find include file <stdlib.h>.

I think I found the problem but how do I solve this
[image: problem image]

has u can see in the image the system directories that look for includes are wrong because they have "/gneaubi" twice, the question is how do I change this

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

It seems that problem is coming from Netbeans IDE.
I would suggest to follow this once and check if the problem is rectified.

- Right-click your project and go to properties.
- In the properties, click run and change the console type to standard output.

P.S: Please provide proper info about the error by hovering mouse on error ballon. Given info is not sufficient currently.